# SQL Query with partial match required

Tags: mysql, sql

I run a gym and am trying to query my database to find out how many customers who signed up to the intro class also signed up to the next level class. For starters I am issuing a simple SQL command as follows:

```
Select * from 'classes' where 'name' = '4 Week Intro Class'
```

This comes back with zero matches because I assume there is no match due to the name of the class also contains dates and times.  I want to only match on the partial class name not the whole name.  I've tried = and LIKE and MATCH to no avail.

Once I get this result then I want to expand it further to show me all the customers who took this class also took the next level class name.  Baby steps.

I can provide more info if needed. I'm using MySQL btw.

Thanks.
Ed

Comment: can you provide the list of all rows in 'classes' table?

Comment: Sure thing, is there a quick way to query for this info?

Answer (score 1):

For your first query, there are no matches because you are comparing two strings, and they are not equal.  Presumably, you intend:

```
Select *
from classes
where name = '4 Week Intro Class';
```

*Only* use single quotes for string and date constants.

You can use `like` by doing:

```
Select *
from classes
where name like '%Intro%';
```

When you ask another question, include sample data and desired results, as well as your attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Partial texts 
id
name
name_orig
level
instructor1_id
instructor2_id
price
show_in_registration
show_in_schedule
allow_student_discount
free_for_instructors
max_registrations
location
start_date
end_date
start_time
end_time
duration_num
duration_type
dates
notes
record_time
allow_groupon
send_level_up_email

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
252
Level 1 Thu Apr 15 to May 20 at 5:30pm
1
2197
2195
135.00
1
1
1
0
10
0
2010-04-15
2010-05-20
00:00:00
00:00:00
6
WEEK
NULL
2010-04-06 08:39:05
0
0

Comment: Thanks this worked, it now shows me the data I'm looking for.  So now that I have a list of all classes with this criteria match how can I narrow it down by how many students that took this class?  Then, I want to find out from the results how many students went on to take more classes.  Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

Comment: 155 students signed up for the intro class

Comment: from the 155 students 78 continued to sign up for the level 1 class and 50 signed up for the level 2 class.

Comment: @EdTruman . . . Ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Here is a list of columns in classes: